# Command line switch to disable Coherence?

Tags: cache, java

We have a Java app that happens to have the coherence jar in the path.

My application doesn't need it, so I'd like to pass some type of -D variable to the JVM to tell it to ignore coherence, or perhaps send it to a no-op cache / tangsol config file?

I've been on the Oracle site but haven't found this yet.  I admit I don't know much about Coherence.  Removing the jar from the app would be awkward at best, it'd be better to handle this through configuration.

Thannks

Comment: If you don't need the coherence stuff then remove it. Why would that be "awkward"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name a long story, but basically this process uses a few Coherence utility classes, POF for example, but talks to another service that is already talking to Coherence.  After more experiments I tried rephrasing the question and posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11889029/295802)

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that you should ask about this. There are other requests for the same (e.g. some sort of command line flag to "disable" Coherence), and I believe that it is planned for an upcoming release (either the currently-rolling-out 12.1.3 or the following release).

Is there anything in specific that you see Coherence "doing" that you're trying to avoid?

*(Disclaimer: I work at Oracle, including on Oracle Coherence.)*

Comment: Wow, this was 2 years and 1 job ago, so I'm rusty on the pain that I was having. It was nested several levels deep so I couldn't easily remove it, and I think at that time there was some system-wide configuration that they were working on but that there was no published workaround for.  This is one of things that a coherence guru could have either fixed the config or configured a workaround, but I knew very little about coherence.  I just wanted to test my stuff locally, so didn't need it, didn't want it, but couldn't ignore its presence.